# Rails 6 form_for radio_buttons Not Submitting Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`ruby 3.1.1, Rails 6.1.4`

I am having problems with a rails form.  I'm using 'form_for' with a couple of radio button form elements. The form submits, but values for the radio button elements come across as "0".  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This part of my app is named spaced:  root/living_muay_thai/

```
Migration:

class CreateLivingMuayThaiSummitSurveys < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :living_muay_thai_summit_surveys do |t|

      t.string  :question_1  # radio button
      t.string  :question_2  # radio button
      t.text    :question_3
      t.text    :question_4
      t.text    :question_5

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end




Controller 

class LivingMuayThai::SummitSurveysController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @summit_survey = LivingMuayThai::SummitSurvey.new
  end


  def create
    survey = LivingMuayThai::SummitSurvey.new(summit_survey_params)

    if survey.save
      flash[:notice]="Your survey has been submitted"
      redirect_to(living_muay_thai_summit_surveys_thank_you_url)
    else
      flash[:notice]="Sorry, your survey could not be saved. Try Again?"
      redirect_to( new_living_muay_thai_summit_survey_url)
    end
  end
  ...

  def summit_survey_params
    params.require(:living_muay_thai_summit_survey).permit(:question_1, :question_2, :question_3,:question_4, :question_5)
  end
end



Form

<%= form_for(@summit_survey) do |f| %>

  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell medium-12">
      <label for="problem"><strong>
        1) How likely are you to attend a future LMT Summit?
      </strong></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="medium-5">
      <%= f.radio_button :question_1, 'One' %> <label>One</label><br />
      <%= f.radio_button :question_1, 'Two' %> <label>Two</label><br />
      <%= f.radio_button :question_1, 'Three' %> <label>Three</label><br />
      <%= f.radio_button :question_1, 'Four' %> <label>Four</label><br />
      <%= f.radio_button :question_1, 'Five' %> <label>Five</label>
  </div>
```

When I view-source or Inspect the radio_button elements in the browser, it all seems correct:

```
<input type="radio" value="One" name="living_muay_thai_summit_survey[question_1]" id="living_muay_thai_summit_survey_question_1_one" /> <label>One</label><br />
<input type="radio" value="Two" name="living_muay_thai_summit_survey[question_1]" id="living_muay_thai_summit_survey_question_1_two" /> <label>Two</label><br />
<input type="radio" value="Three" name="living_muay_thai_summit_survey[question_1]" id="living_muay_thai_summit_survey_question_1_three" /> <label>Three</label><br />
<input type="radio" value="Four" name="living_muay_thai_summit_survey[question_1]" id="living_muay_thai_summit_survey_question_1_four" /> <label>Four</label><br />
<input type="radio" value="Five" name="living_muay_thai_summit_survey[question_1]" id="living_muay_thai_summit_survey_question_1_five" /> <label>Five</label>
```

When I submit a record, I get no errors. But when I view the record in the console, I see "0" and "0" for 'question_1' and 'question_2', not the "one" and "two" I entered.

```
s=LivingMuayThai::SummitSurvey.last

:010 > s
#<LivingMuayThai::SummitSurvey:0x00007f66b66a4c20
 id: 7,                                 
 question_1: "0",                       
 question_2: "0",                       
 question_3: "test 3",                     
 question_4: "test 4",                    
 question_5: "test 5",                     
 created_at: Mon, 17 Oct 2022 16:12:17.047229000 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 17 Oct 2022 16:12:17.047229000 EDT -04:00>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  My "guess" is it is something in the radio_button code on the form, but as I noted, it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working.  I rewrote the radio buttons on my form, from scratch, and viola! it started working.  I compared the old and new code and cannot see what is different, but it works.

Shrugging my shoulders.

Thanks for looking!